# How to define and quantify computational work across different machines and encodings

Tags: time-complexity

Say I have the following intsruction represented in a number of languages:

```
| Language                   |                    Instruction                           |
|----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| English                    |                                          add six to five |
| Python                     |                                                      6+5 |
| Assembly                   |                                                 ADD(6,5) |
| MachineX,BinaryEncoding1   | 01111100000001111111100010101010101010101010101010101011 |
| MachineX,BinaryEncoding2   |       01111100000001111111100111111111111010101010101011 |
| MachineY,TernaryEncoding2  |                                 021021212121200202120202 |
| MachineZ,100004aryEncoding |                                                        p |
```

How might I compare the amount of computational work done by each machine? Perhaps clock operations? What framework might I use to better articulate what I mean by "computational work"?

What if the number of possible inputs implied by the original instruction was variable as well, say:

> Send message "hello dad" from virtual commodore 64 to virtual commodore VIC20 via virtual SMS

Comment: What do you mean with the "amount of computational work"? If you are talking about time or space, the answer to your question is "the entire field of computational complexity theory".

Comment: What you are comparing depends on *why* you are comparing. What goal are you trying to achieve? Also, how about measuring the execution "wall time" on each of the machines?

Comment: @quicksort thanks. Are there alternatives to time and space?  I think the field of Algorithmic Information Theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_information_theory). You are probably right with that answer!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks, I'd like to design (or understand how one might) a virtual machine with optimised resource (time,space) footprint for a known (v large) set of instructions (instruction space?). Still grappling with terminology at the moment.

Comment: @quicksort in answer to your question; I'm not certain. I'm asking, in part, to find out what definitions exist.

Comment: @atomh33ls Then we are back to Yuval's question. What's your goal? What are you trying to do? As it is, you're asking something so broad we can't give a proper answer.